# Angular creating a "third party module", handling Data, or getting data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a module which will primarily be used as a "third party" module. The intention is to create something that can be easily adapted into other Angular applications. So what I have so far, is something like this.

**Someone else's application:**

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'myApp', ['thirdPartyModule'] );
```

**My Third Party Module:**

```
angular.module('thirdPartyModule', [])
.controller('thirdPartyController', function($scope, getDataForThirdPartyModule)
{
    getDataForThirdPartyModule.getData().then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.thirdPartyData = data;
        console.log($scope.thirdPartyData);
    });
})
.factory('getDataForThirdPartyModule', function($http)
{
    return {
        getData: function (callback) {
            return $http.get('/path/to/sample-data.json').then(function(response)
            {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

*Currently this works with the hard coded URL path:*

```
$http.get('/path/to/sample-data.json')
```

But what I would like to know is what would be the best way to do this? My idea would be to not have the URL path hard coded, but dynamic and determined by the main application or module. For example, my first thought was something like this...

```
$http.get($scope.thirdpartyUrl);
```

But that doesn't work, or seem right. So what would be a good or right way to do something like this?

Comment: simple to add an argument or arguments to the `getData()` method and resolve the url inside the service based on some sort of action descriptions passed in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe):

```
.provider('getDataForThirdPartyModule', function () {
  // In the provider function, you cannot inject any
  // service or factory. This can only be done at the
  // "$get" method.

  this.url = '/path/to/sample-data.json'; // default url

  this.$get = function ($http) {
    var url = this.url;
    return {
      getData: function (callback) {
        return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
          return response.data;
        });
      }
    }
  };

  this.setUrl = function (url) {
    this.url = url;
  };
});
```

And then you can configure your provider in your app:

```
myApp.config(function(getDataForThirdPartyModuleProvider){
    getDataForThirdPartyModuleProvider.setUrl('/path/to/sample-data.json');
});
```

Check [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uxPE4dhmozyCkRPVkcgU?p=preview).

Comment: Hmm.. getting this error now `Unknown provider: $http`

Comment: Can you try to wrap your $get function: `['$http', function($http){...`?

Comment: Okay, I think I was getting that because I forgot to remove `$http` out of the `function($http)` like you had suggested. But then I didn't clear my console. However, I am getting this error. `Unknown provider: getDataForThirdPartyModuleProvider`

Comment: Added a plnkr example

Comment: Okay, thanks. I see you are passing `getDataForHierarchyModule` to the `myApp` controller. Whereas I am trying to pass it to the controller inside the `thirdPartyModule`.

Comment: You can pass the `getDataForThirdPartyModuleProvider` wherever you like. Updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uxPE4dhmozyCkRPVkcgU?p=preview)

Comment: Basically the idea was to give the data to the `thirdPartyModule` or give the URL to `thirdPartyModule` to get the data. And then let it handle rendering it and updating it.

Comment: Cool, got it working. Thanks for your time and patience. I must of had a typo or something cause I had it exactly like your second example.

Comment: I see what I did wrong.. I had changed the names of `getDataForThirdPartyModule` and `getDataForThirdPartyModuleProvider`. And didn't realize they had to use the same name as the provider.. For example `xyzModuleProvider` and `xyzModule` vs `xxxModuleProvider` and `xyzModule`